# How to get values from selected cells DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I get to get values from selected cells DataGridView C# ?
not one

i need many one , all what i selected to save in db

in windows form

i want to check every cell in the first Column and then get its value "id"

this Column is a combo box

Comment: Your question is incomplete is it aspnet, winform, wpf ? you need to add more context to your question

Comment: i want to check every cell in the first Column and then get its value "id"

this Column is a combo box
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEjH.png

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
    DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection DGV = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
    for (int i = 0; i <= DGV.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DGV [i].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection t = this.theDataGridView.SelectedRows;

object theValue = this.theDataGridView.Rows[t[0].Index].Cells[index].Value;
```

Loop the Datagridview
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
       Label lbl1=new lable();

```
   lbl1=(label) cell.findcontrol('lbl');

}
```

}

find the rowindex of the selected the rows and find the controls, you will get all the selected rows.

Comment: This doesn't get the selected cells as requested

Comment: i use it but there are error

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvFishStatis.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[2]; //Note specified column index
                    if (cell.Value != null )
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dgvFishStatis.Rows[dgvFishStatis.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()]);
                    }

                     
                }

Comment: dataGridView1.CurrentRow[e.RowIndex].ToString(); can you try this

Comment: i want to check every cell in the first Column and then get its value "id"

this Column is a combo box

Comment: i want to check every cell in the first Column and then get its value "id"

this Column is a combo box
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEjH.png